# maxReceivedMessageSize on Azure WCF service is too small

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure

Whenever I connect my client to send data to my WCF Azure service, I get this error:

"The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To
 increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding 
 element."

I've read everywhere about setting this MaxReceivedMessageSize property on both the client and server config files. I have done this.

However, whenever I update the service reference in the client, it pulls the settings back to the default of 65536. (found via investigating the .svcinfo file)

This leads me to conclude the issue must be on the service side.

I've placed this in my web.config file:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <!--The basicHttpBinding is used for clients which use the generated code to transmit data; the following settings make it possible to send larger amounts to the service-->
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" receiveTimeout="01:00:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10000000" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Now, many posts talk about naming the binding and setting it in the service endpoints on the server side as well. Something like this:

```
<services>
   <service name="YourNamespace.YourServiceClass">
       <endpoint name="endpoint1"
             address="http://server:8888/YourService.svc" 
             binding="basicHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="lageMessageTransfer"
             contract="IYourServiceContract" />
   </service>
</services>
```

However, I don't have these service endpoints and my service works great for small sizes.

Where else would this need to be set?

**EDIT:**

More information, Tim seems to be on the right track with the default endpoints. I am using a default endpoint. It seems that you cannot just explicitly define a service for that default endpoint. or if you can, I must be doing it incorrectly.

However, it seems that you can modify the binding on a default endpoint as stated by Richard. This is done by simply not specifying a name for the binding. I have tried setting the values on my service to much lower values to see if something else was lowering them, but they are completely ignored. Its as if the default endpoint is simply ignoring the binding that I have created.

For my entire config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" />
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing" propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="sdt" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="logging.e2e" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,  PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="100" maxBufferSize="100" receiveTimeout="00:11:00">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="100" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
</protocolMapping>

<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" /> 
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
<connectionStrings><EDITEDOUT></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Thoughts on why the new binding settings are not being picked up?

Comment: Unfortunately, to my knowledge, you're stuck if you can't modify the service's configuration.  If you absolutely cannot modify the service's configuration you'll need to take steps to ensure that your payload is less than the 65536 byte maximum.

Comment: I can modify the server's configuration, however, it will not pick up the new settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have the  section in the Web.config on your service side?  If you're using WCF 4.0 is it possible you're using a default endpoint?

I don't know if you can specify a binding for a default endpoint, but you might want to try specifying an endpoint via the  section of the Web.config and setting bindingConfiguration to the binding specified in your  section.

Comment: I tried explicitly defining a new service endpoint, with no address: 

    <services>
      <service name="TimesheetService.TimesheetSvc">
        <endpoint contract="MyService" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" />
      </service>
    </services>  

No luck, although this seems like its on the right path. Is there anyway to trace through and see if something is mis-entered in the config?

Comment: Can you post the entire config file? Chances are something isn't matching up in the config file.

Comment: posted inline with the original question.

Comment: Is this the client or the server's config file? Since the message is being received by the client, the settings have to be adjusted in the server's client configuration file. The config file you wrote above *should* work as I understand the changes in 4.0.

Comment: If you cannot edit the server's config file, then I believe GunnerL3510 above has the right answer for you.

Comment: This is the server's config file. Also, I am getting the error of the message size being too big when I send data back to the server, not when retrieving data. So it should be the server file with the issue right?

Comment: Yes, it should be the server's file. Can you share the code you're using to make the WCF call to the server?

Comment: One more idea to try.  Set up a specific endpoint in the server's config file, give a name to the binding in the <bindings> section, and specify that name in the bindingConfiguration attribute of the endpoint.  That way you can verify if the service is picking up the binding settings you specified.

Comment: As of recently, I have been using just the WCF Test Client, and checking what config file it picks up.

I tried adding a new custom endpoint, it ran the service, but none of the new values were picked up. I checked out the trace log, and it shows that a duplicate configuration was found and the more recent one was used.

Comment: I just recreated the whole service from scratch following every instruction to the letter. The new service works. Sadly, I'm not sure what the original problem was. I'm marking this as correct as the default endpoint comment lead me down the most productive path. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The attribute name maxReceivedMessageSize is very explicit - it all depends on who is receiving the message - if you are sending a large amount of data then it is the service, if you are getting a large amount of data back from the service then it is the client. The service and client do not need the same value for this setting (unlike many other binding settings)

Setting an unnamed binding section should work in general as, of .NET 4, it configures the binding for anyone who doesn't explicitly specify a configuration using bindingConfiguration. However, in your example above you need to set the maxBufferSize in addition to the maxReceivedMessageSize as you are buffering rather than streaming the message. The maxBufferSize and maxReceivedMessageSize must be the same

Comment: I set maxBufferSize as well. Same issue. If I look in the configuration.svcinfo file that gets updated whenever I update the service reference, you can see that it is still pulling the default values for all of the various properties.

Comment: The client will see the default values as these values are often different on the client and service. As I said above they refer to the receiver of the data. Can you try this: reduce the maxReceivedMessageSize and maxBufferSize so they are below the default and send a message that will still work. However, return the bindings actual maxReceivedMessageSize from the service just to make sure its not getting picked up and something else isn;t getting in the way

Comment: ((BasicHttpBinding)OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Endpoints[0].Binding).MaxReceivedMessageSize should give you what you need